# Locking rows in a table for SELECT and UPDATE

Tags: sql, database-design, postgresql

I am writing a script that needs to book seats in the cinema.

1. User asks for 2 seats
2. If there are 2 seats available, system offers them to client
3. Client can either accept them or request another 2 seats.
4. When he finally accepts, seats are marked as "sold"

Since there can be multiple users using system simultaneously, I need a way to "lock" the rows offered to current client until certain time passes, or he requests another seats.

Currently I am marking offered seats as "locked" with a client id, and use SELECT to return them to the client (this is for MySQL, but target database is Postgres)

```
UPDATE seats SET status = "locked", lock_time = NOW(), lock_id = "lock1" LIMIT 2
SELECT * FROM seats WHERE lock_id = "lock1" AND lock_time > DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 2 MINUTE)
```

There is a problem with that: if there's only 1 seat available, it will still be marked as "locked" and I will have to release lock right away.

I am also pretty sure that there is a smarter way of doing that. What is the correct way of dealing with a task like that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*Race Condition*  - I think this would be better as an insert rather than an update. Two updates can run at the same time and they will not conflict with each other. If you had 'locked seats' table then you could reference the seat_id and make it unique. That way a race conditions would fail. But, in any case, I wrote this as an update as you have in the question although you could change it to an insert.

It seems like you just do not want to be able to lock the seats in the first place if there are not enough available. This is easy with self joins:

```
create temp table seats
(
    id          serial,
    event_id    integer,
    locked      boolean default false
);
insert into seats (event_id) values (1),(1),(1),(2);
-- this will not lock event_id = 2 since it will not have a high enough count
update seats
set locked = true
from
(
    -- get the counts so we can drop events without enough seats
    select count(*), event_id from seats group by event_id
) as sum,
(
    -- you can not put limits in update; need to self-join
    select id from seats limit 2
) as t
where sum.event_id = seats.event_id
and seats.id = t.id
and count >= 2
```

;

```
UPDATE 2
 id | event_id | locked 
----+----------+--------
  3 |        1 | f
  4 |        2 | f
  2 |        1 | t
  1 |        1 | t
(4 rows)
```

So this 'locks' two seats for every event that has at least two seats :)

Comment: Thanks, decided to go with your solution. Had to modify query a bit, but it works as expected

Answer (score 3):

What you are discussing is a reservation system. The way I've built such systems is to have a table of reservations and table of seats.

```
Create Table Reservations
    (
    EventId ... not null References Events ( Id )
    , SeatNumber varchar(10) not null
    , Expiration datetime not null
    , CustomerId ... not null References Customers( Id )
    , Constraint FK_Reservations_Seats
        Foreign Key( EventId, SeatNumber )
        References EventSeats( EventId, SeatNumber )
    )

Create Table EventSeats
    (
    EventId ... References Events ( Id )
    , SeatNumber varchar(10) not null
    , CustomerId ... null References Customers( Id )
    , PurchaseDate datetime not null
    )
```

When someone makes a reservation you do an insert into the Reservations table with a datetime value some specified period of time in the future. When you are looking for available seats, your query looks like:

```
Select S.EventId, S.SeatNumber
From EventSeats As S
Where S.EventId = ...
    And S.CustomerId Is Null
    And Not Exists  (
                    Select 1
                    From Reservations As R
                    Where R.EventId = S.EventId
                        And R.SeatNumber = S.SeatNumber
                        And R.Expiration > CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
                    )
```

This allows someone to put a temporary hold on a seat if they want. If they want to purchase the seats, you insert another reservation record for some period into the future. In fact, the system I designed inserted a new reservation on each step of the purchase process that was 10 minutes into the future just to help the user finish the purchase process before the reservation expired. Once they complete the purchase you update the EventSeats table with their information and now this seat is permanently taken.

Comment: Your solution looks very good, I will try applying it, just to see how it compares to the one I accepted.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` which will lock those rows for you -- you can then figure out how many rows you've selected and if there are enough you can update them with the lock value and timestamp. If you no longer want these rows you can `ROLLBACK` to release the locks.
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/sql-select.html#SQL-FOR-UPDATE-SHARE

However these only work for the duration of a transaction, if the transaction is lost, these locks will be released, so you can't use the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` lock to hold the row open, you'll need to mark them as reserved somehow.

In general locking and then waiting on a user response is a bad technique. What if the user leaves to take a shower etc... Then you are left with lots of locked rows.

It seems you have two options:

1. Don't lock anything, if the user tries to select a seat and that is later sold out, just apologize and present them with some other available seats. Also, keep statistics on how often this happens and if you find it happens too often you can consider a locking scheme.
2. Do what you describe in your question, and make some rule that seat reservations expire after 2 minutes etc... This way you don't have to worry about explicitly releasing the locks, you can just check the timestamps of when they were set.

Comment: I don't think German is talking about db level row locking - he is talking about logically "locking" or "reserving" a seat that is offered to one customer so that it is not booked by another customer before a decision is made by the first customer.

Comment: yeah, my answer was slightly unclear, but i meant that he should only use the `SELECT ... FOR UPDATE` to make sure he gets enough rows to satisfy the user request and then put in the lock timestamps  with an update. not to hold the db level lock for the entire duration of the user's decision.

Comment: `select ... for update` does not lock rows for the duration of a connection, but the duration of a transaction

Answer (score 0):

If I have understood your problem correctly, I think a solution could be the following:

make the following transaction(it's in pseudo-code of course)

```
<lock seats table>

  result=SELECT count(*) FROM seats 
   WHERE status="unlocked"
   GROUP BY status
   HAVING count(*)>=2

 IF result EXISTS

    UPDATE seats SET status = "locked", lock_time = NOW(), lock_id = "lock1" 
    WHERE status="unlocked"LIMIT 2


 <unlock seats table>
```

You release table locks quickly this way. Then if user doesn't want the their order you 
can cancel with a simple update. Also locking index doesn't prevent other updates

Another more rational approach IMHO is the following pseudo-code. I think it's a good approach since it's stateless and you don't keep the records locked(using DB locks) waiting for user to decide(which should be avoided at all costs)

```
 result=SELECT * FROM seats 
         WHERE status="unlocked"
 <present the result to the user and let the user decide which n seats they want>
 array[] choices:=<get from the user>

 //note that we do not lock the table here and the available seats presented to the     
 //user might be taken while he is making his choices. But that's OK since we should
 //not keep the table locked while he is making his choices. 

 <lock seats table>
 //now since the user either wants all the seats together or none of them, all the
 //seats rows that they want should be unlocked at first. If any of them
 // is locked when the UPDATE command is updating the row, then we should rollback all 
 // the updates. Unfortunately there is no way to determine that by standard update      
 // command. Thus here I use the following select query before making the update to
 // make sure every choice is there.

 result= SELECT count(*)
         FROM seats
         WHERE status="unlocked" AND seat_id IN (choice[1],choice[2], ...,choice[n])

 IF result=length(choices)

    UPDATE seats SET status = "locked", lock_time = NOW(), lock_id = "lock1" 
     WHERE seat_id IN (choice[1],choice[2], ...,choice[n])

  <unlock seats table>
```

Regards 
Amir

Answer (score 0):

Just an alternative - what is the implication if you just 'let' the next customer also buy the seats and give a error popup to the first user, in case he selects those seats after the first customer has bought them?

The entire use case can be changed somewhat (I am thinking about ticket booking as it happens here) -

Customer selects movie - show timings - is shown a list of **all** empty seats, updated in realtime - with color coding. Then depending on which seats are selected by the customer, those are taken up for payment.

The locking mechanism you are using will always show more seats as sold out than they actually are - which can unnecessarily lead to lost sales. On the other hand, if you just have a simple check when the user actually buys the seats, to check whether the seats have been sold to someone else during the time between retrieving those seats and booking them, then you can always show an error message. Even above, after the customer selects the seats till payment, it is necessary to lock them; but then you won't face the problem of the system selecting the seats, its the customer who chooses them!

Comment: This would be my first choice of doing it, but unfortunately project requirement is that seats should be offered on demand, not selected

Answer (score 0):

Do your update/select statements in a transaction. If you only get one row back, roll back the transaction and the locks will be reverted.